# Is there a name for this function related to partitions of m?

Tags: combinatorics

I’m looking for a name to this particular function if there is one.  $$H(m,n)$$ is the number of ways to partition $m$ into parts of size at most $n$ where order matters. For example, $5=1+2+2$ is different from $5=2+1+2$.